# Sort list based on their i18n translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, internationalization

Given i have a list of items in my DB and their respective translation in i18n file.

i18n file:

```
  basic_categories:  
    item_1: Z
    item_2: A
    item_3: F
```

on the view:

```
      <% @basic_categories.each do |category| %>
        <%= t("basic_categories.#{category.name}") %>
      <% end %>
```

How can i sort this list for each language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have the translation in your database if your list is too long, for performance reason. MySQL sort faster than ruby.

Otherwise I think you could do something like this:

In your controller, use ruby to build an array of string or hash:

```
@basic_categories = categories.collect { |category|
  { :name => I18n.t("basic_categories.#{category.name}"), ... }
}.sort_by { |category| category[:name] }
```

And sort it with ruby, see http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html

In you view simply:

```
<% @basic_categories.each do |category| %>
  <%= category[:name] %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can pass json with translations to PG query and then order by translated value from json:

```
categories_i18n = I18n.backend.instance_variable_get(:@translations).dig(:en, :basic_categories).to_json
@basic_categories = categories.order("'#{categories_i18n}::json'->>name")
```